# Как закрасить svg?

Tags: css, svg

Подскажите, как закрасить svg? т.е. чтобы синим были закрашены не только края, но и внутри.
Можно ли это сделать только с помощью css?

[image: скриншот]

```html
<svg id="like" viewBox="0 0 612 792" width="100%" height="100%"><path d="M610.988,281.167c-8.934-98.326-78.529-169.664-165.627-169.664c-58.025,0-111.154,31.226-141.051,81.271  c-29.625-50.693-80.576-81.283-137.672-81.283c-87.085,0-156.692,71.337-165.614,169.664c-0.706,4.343-3.602,27.2,5.202,64.476  C18.914,399.396,48.221,448.3,90.958,487.022L304.17,680.508l216.872-193.474c42.736-38.734,72.044-87.627,84.731-141.403  C614.578,308.367,611.683,285.51,610.988,281.167z M582.857,340.24c-11.581,49.104-38.429,93.841-77.563,129.292L304.311,648.847  L106.777,469.579c-39.206-35.521-66.041-80.247-77.635-129.351c-8.333-35.274-4.908-55.201-4.896-55.331l0.176-1.189  c7.651-86.144,67.454-148.677,142.216-148.677c55.166,0,103.729,33.897,126.774,88.451l10.84,25.694l10.84-25.694  c22.681-53.718,73.81-88.439,130.281-88.439c74.751,0,134.565,62.534,142.369,149.795  C587.766,285.027,591.19,304.966,582.857,340.24z"></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш `svg` внутри никак не закрасить, т.к. обрамление сердца в нем и есть вся фигура.

Для того, чтобы добиться нужного вам результата, сохраните `svg` вот так:

```css
svg {
  fill: #f00;
  stroke: black; // для демонстрации
  stroke-width: 30px; // для демонстрации
}
```

```html
<svg id="like" viewBox="0 0 612 792" width="100%" height="100%"><path d="M562.413,284.393c-9.68,41.044-32.121,78.438-64.831,108.07L329.588,542.345l-165.11-149.843 c-32.771-29.691-55.201-67.076-64.892-108.12c-6.965-29.484-4.103-46.14-4.092-46.249l0.147-0.994 c6.395-72.004,56.382-124.273,118.873-124.273c46.111,0,86.703,28.333,105.965,73.933l9.061,21.477l9.061-21.477 c18.958-44.901,61.694-73.922,108.896-73.922c62.481,0,112.478,52.27,119,125.208C566.517,238.242,569.379,254.908,562.413,284.393z"/></svg>
```

Чтобы это сделать, откройте ваш исходный в AI , наведите на контур фигуры, нажмите <kbd>ПКМ</kbd> и выберите "Расформировать составной контур". В итоге у вас получится 2 фигуры, которые можете в дальнейшем использовать.

**UPDATE** с учетом комментария про наведение на `svg`:

```css
svg {
  fill: none;
  stroke:#f00;
  stroke-width:30px;
}

svg:hover {
  fill: #f00;
}
```

```html
<svg id="like" viewBox="0 0 612 792" width="100%" height="100%"><path d="M562.413,284.393c-9.68,41.044-32.121,78.438-64.831,108.07L329.588,542.345l-165.11-149.843 c-32.771-29.691-55.201-67.076-64.892-108.12c-6.965-29.484-4.103-46.14-4.092-46.249l0.147-0.994 c6.395-72.004,56.382-124.273,118.873-124.273c46.111,0,86.703,28.333,105.965,73.933l9.061,21.477l9.061-21.477 c18.958-44.901,61.694-73.922,108.896-73.922c62.481,0,112.478,52.27,119,125.208C566.517,238.242,569.379,254.908,562.413,284.393z"/></svg>
```

Comment: а подскажите, как сделать, чтобы закрашивалось только при наведении курсора на svg? Нужны ли здесь две svg, т.е. незакрашенная и закрашенная?

Comment: @word при наведении на весь `svg` или на саму фигуру? Сейчас `svg` сделан так, что по бокам от фигуры пустые места. Это нужно учитывать.

Comment: по бокам не нужны никакие места. При наведении на svg, я ведь про это спрашиваю, как закрасить svg? А что, эти боковые места никак нельзя удалить?

Comment: @word в AI откорректирую монтажную область так, чтобы ваша фигура прилегала к ее краям.

Comment: меня больше интересует вопрос про то, можно ли сделать ховер только с одним svg?

Comment: @word обновил ответ

Comment: сейчас фигуру видно только при наведении, если убрать курсор, фигуру не видно.

Comment: вы так и не ответили, можно ли сделать это одной фигурой?

Comment: @word это и так одной фигурой сделано

Comment: @word уточню, что `:hover` можно применять не только к `svg`, но и ко всем элементам внутри этого `svg`, например, к `path`, как в вашем случае

Comment: а подскажите, как убрать лишние отступы сверху и снизу у svg? , т.е. сейчас, если svg поместить в контейнер, и задать для контейнера высоту и ширину, то svg растянется не  на всю ширину высоту из-за лишних отступов. Разве эти отступы нельзя как-то сразу удалить, чтобы не мешали?

Comment: @Alexandr_T, как можно удалить лишние отступы у svg?

Comment: @Alexandr_T я же писал в комментарии выше - это делается в Adobe Illustrator или в любом другом редакторе

Comment: а можно ли убрать отступы, редактируя свойство viewBox ?

Comment: @word нет, нельзя

Answer (score 3):

### SVG анимация заливки

Анимация реализуется с использованием фильтра `<feFlood>`

У  `feOffset` анимируется атрибут `dy`  от `1` - незакрашен, до `0` - полностью закрашен

```
<feOffset dy="1">
        <animate attributeName="dy" begin="ph.mouseover" from="1" to="0" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
      </feOffset>
```

Начало анимации при наведении курсора на контур сердца

`begin="ph.mouseover"`, где `ph` ID контура сердца.

```html
<svg id="like" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 50 612 792" width="100%" height="100%">
 <defs>
    <filter id="fillHeart" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feFlood x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" flood-color="red" />
      <feOffset dy="1">
        <animate attributeName="dy" begin="ph.mouseover" from="1" to="0" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
<path id="ph" transform="scale(0.45)" filter="url(#fillHeart)" style="fill:white;stroke:red; stroke-width:2;" 

d="M562.413,284.393c-9.68,41.044-32.121,78.438-64.831,108.07L329.588,542.345l-165.11-149.843 c-32.771-29.691-55.201-67.076-64.892-108.12c-6.965-29.484-4.103-46.14-4.092-46.249l0.147-0.994 c6.395-72.004,56.382-124.273,118.873-124.273c46.111,0,86.703,28.333,105.965,73.933l9.061,21.477l9.061-21.477 c18.958-44.901,61.694-73.922,108.896-73.922c62.481,0,112.478,52.27,119,125.208C566.517,238.242,569.379,254.908,562.413,284.393z" />
</svg>
```